# Python - Add nested items to one nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I am trying to create one nested Python dictionary called Results.

I am using AWS Rekognition to get an image and output the results.

The results_dict only contains one result after it's complated, and I wish to have all the results in one nested loop

I'm trying to get:

```
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "Name": "Human",
            "Confidence": 98.87621307373047,
        },
                {
            "Name": "Face",
            "Confidence": 98.87621307373047,
        },
        {
            "Name": "Person",
            "Confidence": 98.87621307373047,
        },
        
    ]
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
{
    'Results': 
        {
          'Name': 'Paper', 
          'Confidence': 57.299766540527344
        }
}
```

The code is replacing the text, and I want to add another set of Name and Confidence.

My code is:

```
import boto3
import json

BUCKET = "*****"

FOLDER = 'testing/'
JOEY =  FOLDER + "Joey_30_Sept.png"
BEYONCE = FOLDER + "beyonce_rekognition_moderation_testing.jpg"
MANBEARD = FOLDER + "man_beard.jpg"
MEN = FOLDER + "men_group.jpg"


client = boto3.client('rekognition')
                                
response = client.detect_labels(Image=
                                {'S3Object': {
                                    'Bucket': BUCKET,
                                    'Name': JOEY
                                }},
                                MaxLabels = 10,
                                MinConfidence=0)
 

results_dict = {}
results_dict['Results'] = {}
results_dict['Results']['Name'] = ""
results_dict['Results']['Confidence'] = ""
               
for label in response['Labels']:
    name = label['Name'] #to get the whole bounding box.
    confidence = label['Confidence'] 
    
    name_str = str(name)
    conf_str = str(confidence)
    
    results_dict["Results"]["Name"] = label['Name']
    results_dict["Results"]["Confidence"] = label['Confidence']

print(results_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `results_dict['Results']` as dictionary as dict not list:

```
...
results_dict = {}
results_dict['Results'] = []
results_dict['Results']['Name'] = ""
results_dict['Results']['Confidence'] = ""
               
for label in response['Labels']:
    name = label['Name'] #to get the whole bounding box.
    confidence = label['Confidence'] 
    
    name_str = str(name)
    conf_str = str(confidence)
    
    results_dict['Results'].append({["Name": name_str, "Confidence": conf_str })
print(results_dict)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I had been working on coding all day with no break. I needed another set of eyes to see the error. Thanks.